# How to prevent hook running in WooCommerce email notifications

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, email-notifications

I have written this function to display category and category id on the order received page of WooCommerce.

However I wish to disable showing this on WooCommerce order emails. Any advice?

```php
// Display order items product categories and ids
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'display_custom_data_in_emails', 10, 4 );
function display_custom_data_in_emails( $item_id, $item, $order, $bool ) {
    // Get the product categories for this item
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $item->get_product_id(), 'product_cat', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );
  $term_ids = wp_get_post_terms( $item->get_product_id(), 'product_cat', array('fields' => 'ids') );
    
    // Output a coma separated string of product category names
    echo "<br><small>" . implode(', ', $terms) . "</small>";
      echo "<br><small>" . implode(', ', $term_ids) . "</small>";
    
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `! is_wc_endpoint_url()` to determine whether it is an email notification

So you get:

```php
function action_woocommerce_order_item_meta_end( $item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text ) {   
    // NOT on emails notifications
    if ( ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) return;
    
    // Get the product categories for this item
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $item->get_product_id(), 'product_cat', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );
    $term_ids = wp_get_post_terms( $item->get_product_id(), 'product_cat', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
    
    // Output a coma separated string of product category names
    echo "<br><small>" . implode( ', ', $terms ) . "</small>";
    echo "<br><small>" . implode( ', ', $term_ids ) . "</small>";
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'action_woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 10, 4 );
```

**OR** to target only the order received (thankyou) page:

```php
if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ) {
    // do something
}
```